# Selenium xpath selector

Tags: selenium, xpath

So I'm trying to make a Selenium script, and I have this div which should be clicked. I'm trying to find its element but it never seems to find it. I'm trying to find it by Xpath because the id and class changes everyday. This is what the div looks like on inspection:

Edit: I just noticed that there were multiple squares with the same guielement value. However, there is one thing that stands out from the rest and that is the background color of the inner div, which looks like this:

```
<div id="c6S_7P" class="a0 b0 c0 d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j5 k0 l0" cls_n="a0 b0 c0 
d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j5 k0 l0" cls_pd="a0 b0 c0 d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j7 k0 l0" lmask="
[MC][ME]" mpar="c6S_7O" mtype="group" readonly="true" style="display: block; 
visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 83px; height: 34px; 
background-color: rgb(187, 255, 255);">
```

Parent div:

```
<div id="c6S_4N" class="a0 b0 c0 d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j5 k0 l0" cls_n="a0 b0 c0 
d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j5 k0 l0" cls_pd="a0 b0 c0 d0 e1 f2 h0 i10 j7 k0 l0" 
mpar="c6S_23" mtype="group" readonly="true" style="display: block; 
visibility: visible; top: 152px; left: 233px; width: 614px; height: 194px;">
```

Is there a way to find the element by the css-value for background-color?

[Screenshot of the relevant part of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Jlr.png)
I need the script to click the blue box.

Comment: if this is related to graph and it's inside svg element. Try searching svg on this forum and you will find your answer.

Comment: `"//*div"` is invalid `XPath`- you need to use `"//*"` to match any node or `"//div"` to match `div` only

Comment: @GaurangShah Searching for SVG in pageinspection does not return any results.

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for that information, however I tried both "//*" and "//div" and neither worked.

Comment: is it highchart component ? if you are not sure ask developer. if it's this question has been aswerd here multiple time. if not, post parent element as well.

Comment: @NathanRuth, can you share page URL?

Comment: @Andersson No sorry, because you have to be logged in to see that. I could screenshot the relevant parts of the source however.

Comment: @NathanRuth, attached screenshot couldn't help much. Can you share more of `HTML` source code?

Comment: Share the html code for the parents of the element u want to click

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[local-name()='div' And @guielement='DAY_AREA_THIS_MONTH_WORKING_DAY']
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Having noticed the above code snippet, I can see that attributes `cls_pd` and `cls_n` are equal in parent and the child. So, using that we can write an Xpath as mentioned below:

```
.//div[@cls_pd=./div/@cls_pd]/div
```

Hope this helps.